# How to get SOAP XML elements from HTTP POST Request (Android)?

Tags: java, android, xml, soap, http-post

I am new to android and  need some help. I have successfully received a response for a HTTP Post request in XML(String results). How can I get an element and its value from the XML(SOAP)? I have looked up Node and Node List but I am unable to retrieve individual node or text value?
Any help will be really appreciated. I have looked kSOAP 2 and other forums but no luck. Thanks in advance.

Here is a part of code which I need to fix to retrieve XML elements (CreditsUsed, Isok) from the response. The code is in doInBackground class in AsyncTask.

```
   InputStream inputStream = null;
   String results = "";
   String responseCode = "";

   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   inputStream = entity.getContent();

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   sb.append(line + "\n");
   }

   results = sb.toString();

   //Posible Solution
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
   InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
   Document doc;
   doc = db.parse(is);


   NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("CreditsUsed");
   Node node = nl.item(0);
   responseCode = node.getTextContent();
   //responseCode = nl.item(0).getNodeValue();



   return STRING; //results or responseCode
```

Here is my SOAP response (String results)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Header>
    <QAInformation xmlns="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03">
        <StateTransition>Unknown</StateTransition>
        <CreditsUsed>0</CreditsUsed>
    </QAInformation>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <QASearchOk xmlns="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03">
        <IsOk>true</IsOk>
    </QASearchOk>
</soap:Body>
```